# extracting data from docx files in python

Tags: parsing, python-3.x, docx

I want to extract data from a word document with extension docx. This document contains a table. I want to fetch the data from each column and row of the table.

then I would like to process the data and insert it into an Excel file under their respective fields.

Can anyone please guide me how to do this in python.

I am using python3 on windows 7. (Might also want to run this code on windows sever 2003).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but parsing is unlikely to work. You'll have to run Word, and talk to it from Python via COM, using the PyWin32 module and it's COM support. It's not going to be easy. :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies.
@LennartRegebro,  How do I proceed with PyWin32?

Comment: 1. You install it. 2. You google for how to do what you want. 3. You come back here with specific questions.

Comment: ... and then you have to learn the object structure when working with the MS Word components.  Beware, it is not extremely easy.

Comment: There's a module that claims to be able to read docx files: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import win32com.client as w32c

Word = w32c.Dispatch("Word.Application")
Word.Visible=1
doc=Word.Documents.Open("C:\\docx_with_a_table.docx")
tables=doc.Tables
for t_cnt in range(tables.Count):
    table=tables[t_cnt]
    for r_cnt in range(table.Rows.Count):
        row=table.Rows[r_cnt]
        for c_cnt in range(row.Cells.Count):
            cell=row.Cells[c_cnt]
            print(cell.Range.Text)
```

ALT+F11 and F2 on a Word doc will show VBA objects... In Perl the above procedure is better documented.

Reading and writing to Excel is well supported by Python3's packages xlrd3 and xlwt3