# How do you convert a table that is in a .docx file to an .xlsx or a csv file in python or R?

Tags: r

I have a document like the one mentioned below. There is some text above the table and then there's a table. How do I extract table from the docx file in R or python and then convert it to a csv file or an xlsx file. I don't even mind a .txt file if it retains the exact format of the table. I just don't know what to do with this doc file.

[image: image of text and table in MS word]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360339/extracting-data-from-docx-files-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If the document is docx, then it is all XML.  The docx file is just a zip container with various XML "parts".  Take a look at the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) for some ideas on how to parse the file.  This SDK is C#, but maybe you can get some ideas from that.

If you are just going to extract the table it should not be too bad ( Updating complex docx documents can get very complicated.  I'm working on this now.)  My tip to make things easier is to go to the table properties, then to the Alt Text tab and add a unique value to the "Title" field.  The value will show up like this within the table properties: `<w:tblCaption w:val="TBL1"/>`, which will make the table easier to extract from the XML.

If you are going to work with Open XML documents, get the [OOXML Chrome Addin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ooxml-tools/bjmmjfdegplhkefakjkccocjanekbapn?hl=en).  That is great for exploring the internals of docx files.

Note: I saw the link to another SO answer for this.  That uses "automation", which is certainly easier to code, but Office via "automation" on the server is not recommended by MS.

Comment: Hi I have been trying to convert word documents to xml online but somehow it doesn't give me the same result as when I save the docx file as a a word xml document on Microsoft Word itself. Do you have any suggestions on how I can convert a large number of files to .xml? I even tries to unzip the .docx file but it didn't give me a good solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help! I think I have managed to convert all the files to XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract tables from docx using `python-docx` in python.
Try this:

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
document = Document(file_path)
tables = []
for index,table in enumerate(document.tables):
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            df[i][j] = cell.text
        pd.DataFrame(df).to_excel("Table# "+str(index)+".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to copy a word table to a xlsx file in R :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\word_File_Table.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
word_Table <- doc$Tables(1)
word_Table$Range()$Copy()

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\empty_Excel_File.xlsx")
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()
Sheets[[1]]$Range("A1")$PasteSpecial(Paste = -4163) # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype
```

To convert a docx file to a txt file, you can use the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\text.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs2(FileName = "D:\\text.txt", FileFormat = 2)
```

To save a word table to CSV, you can consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\Dropbox\\Reponses_Stackoverflow\\stackoverflow_399\\word_File_Table.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
word_Table <- doc$Tables(1)
word_Table$Range()$Copy()

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:\\empty_Excel_File.xlsx")
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()
Sheets[[1]]$Range("A1")$PasteSpecial(Paste = -4163) # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype
xlWbk$SaveAs("D:\\empty_Excel_File.csv", FileFormat = 23) # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat
```